# Curiosities about libsynctex

Tags: packages, texlive, forward-inverse-search

I've browsed through the CTAN repository, and there's no package called libsynctex, and that's also the case with the install script. However, when using linux distributions, e.g. `texlive-bin` of Arch Linux, it gets installed. Why would something non existent on CTAN appear on distributions?

Comment: the sources for tex web2c implementations generally are not on ctan, synctex gets built if you compile the texlive sources from the texlive svn (or its git mirror)

Comment: That's helpful. But how can I get those packages if they aren't listed on CTAN?

Comment: https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/web2c/synctexdir/synctex.c